# Calculate efficiency for insertion sort and merge sort(daa)

Tags: c++, c

Assume that a CPU can process 10^8 operations per second. Suppose you have to sort an array with 10^6 elements?

What is the time taken by insertion sort n merge sort in hr?

Want to know how to calculate the time.

Comment: In the Northern or Southern hemisphere?

Comment: How fast are the tape drives, and how quickly can the operator change the reels?

Comment: If this is indeed a homework question, I suggest you find another college where they ask meaningful questions.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) will not answer your question, but it will be more beneficial to you than the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The information given is insufficient to give an exact answer to the question.

The time taken will depend on data itself and the implementation of the algorithm.

It is, of course, possible to make an estimate based on reasonable assumptions.

Insertion sort is `O(n^2)`, so it will take in the order of `K1 * 10^12` operations to sort the array, or `K1 * 10^4` seconds. Insertion sort would probably take several hours, even with an optimized implementation.

Merge sort is `O(n * log n)`, so it will take in the order of `K2 * 10^6 * 6` operations to sort the array, or `K2 * 6 * 10^(-2)` seconds. Merge sort would probably take less than a second.

This example is a good illustrator on why it is important to choose the right algorithm for the job.